# JSF HttpSession attribute becomes null after refresh/redirection

Tags: jsf, httpsession

I'm testing a simple log in with httpsession, so after i authenticate the user i add a user attribute to the http session :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class loginView {
....
  public String connect() {
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      if (authenticated) {
          context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", login);
          return "/home/NewFile?faces-redirect=true";
      } else {
          context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login, try again"));
          login = "";
          pwd = "";
          return null;
      }
  }
}
```

When i call this function from the login view it redirects to `NewFile.xhtml` as it's supposed to do. And inside the said xhtml i display the `"user"` attribute using `#{user}`. So far everything is working fine but when i refresh the page (`NewFile.xhtml`) or when i redirect to another page and try to display `"user"` attribute i get null, is this behavior expected ? does refreshing or redirecting creates another httpsession ? or is it just deleting the attribute i added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i succeeded in solving my problem, turns out it's just a stupid mistake of my part. so i thought i should leave the answer here instead of deleting the question. So here goes : 
After some looking around I have found out that this had to do with the cookies, so i did track the HTTP traffic using chrome's F12 and and it was the server sending new cookies each time I refresh/navigate. And after some more searching and testing i've found out what was causing the session to invalidate, so i was calling a logout function (that invalidates the session) this way : `<h:button outcome="view.logout()"/>` turns out `outcome` executes the function before loading the page so i had to change it to `<p:commandButton action="view.logout()"/>`